# AppArmor "Multiple definitions for hat sanitized_helper" Error Running Firefox Profile in Enforce Mode

Tags: firefox, apparmor

I've made myself an AA profile and am trying to run in enforce mode:

```
aa-enforce /usr/bin/firefox
```

is giving me

```
ERROR: Multiple definitions for hat sanitized_helper in profile (null) exist,bailing out.
```

I've tried using the default AA profile that come with firefox ubuntu deb. I've tried my own profile. I've tried using no profile. Always this error, so I don't think it's the AA profile's fault.

My first question is what is sanitized_helper? Second, can anyone tell how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

the sanitized_helper to my understanding,  is a helper script for apparmor for profiles that have the environment variables sanitized. perhaps the following will help with understanding better.

http://blog.azimuthsecurity.com/2012/09/poking-holes-in-apparmor-profiles.html